# vb.net, I have only one textbox in the form and the validate event won't fire

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a text box where you can enter a page number and the form will change. I'm using a textbox to allow the user to enter a page number and I want the form to change when the are no longer actively editing the textbox, the problem is that the textbox is the only editable control in the form so it never loses focus and the validating event never fires. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: do that in keypress or keydown event .. on KEYS.RETURN .. and you may add a Button with 'GO' text ..

Comment: The problem I want the user to be able to type more than one digit, which wouldn't work with keypress or keydown. I did thinking about adding a button, but I'd like to be able to do it without that.

Comment: keypress/keydown event wont limit the user to type more than one digit ! Why did you tought so ? ..

Comment: Why don't you add an OK or Update! button, problem solved.  Now your user also knows how to use your program without you having to write a manual.  Two problems solved.

Answer (score 0):

As matzone said use the keypress but not for the page number keys.

For example, say your user wants to goto page "51", then the user can type 51 and press the return key.

Have the events fire on the return key,

```
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
//13 is the keycode for Return

    If (e.KeyCode == 13)
    {
    //SuperAweomseEventGoesHere
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a button as was mentioned to indicate the user wants to load a new page.

Use the validating event to make sure the user entered a valid value.

Alternatively:

If your page numbers are all double digits you could also use the TextChanged event and keep checking if the text value equals a page number.  Having at least 2 digits is important since 1 will load a page and the user won't be able to load 10

Another alternative:

Use a NumberUpDown control or a combobox so the user is restricted to the proper values